# Download File from database using MVC javascript razor

Tags: javascript, file, razor, model-view-controller, download

I display the list of files, (in a database), that I could download in a table.

```
<table style="border: none; width:100%">                
    @for (int i = 0; i <= Model.docs.Count() - 1; i++)
    {
        <tr onclick="downloadFile('@Model.docs[i].id.ToString()')" class="rowFile" data-row=@i id=@("rigaDoc" + i)>
            <td style="border-bottom:1px solid black; width:30px;">
                <img src="@Url.Content(Model.docs[i].icon)" alt="Image" />
            </td>      
            <td style="border-bottom:1px solid black; padding-left: 20px; width:auto;">
                @Html.Label(Model.docs[i].nameFile.ToString().Split('.')[0], new { @class = "" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }          
</table>
```

Once the user clicks on a row of that table, I need to send to the controller the GUID of that row and start the file download.

```js
function downloadFile(fileId) {
    var urlDownload = '@Url.Action("Download", "GestioneDocumenti", new { id = fileId })';
}
```

However, I cannot use fileId because debugger says:

> "the name fileId is not used in this context".

How can I send the information to the controller method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor is server side code and is parsed on the server before it is sent to the view. Change your function to

```
function downloadFile(fileId) {
    var urlDownload = '@Url.Action("Download", "GestioneDocumenti")' + '/' + fileId;
}
```

A better solution would be to generate the url as a `data-` attribute

```
<tr data-url="@Url.Action("Download", "GestioneDocumenti", new { id = Model.docs[i].id })" class="rowFile">
```

and change the script to

```
$('.rowFile').click(function() {
    var urlDownload = $(this).data('url');
});
```

Comment: As a side note, a `<label>` is an accessibility element - clicking on it sets focus to an associated for control. Using `@Html.LabelFor()` is not appropriate in your table